# 17 panel grid of baseplots - layout problem

Tags: r, plot, layout

I have 16 plots made as baseplots that I until now have printed in a 4x4 grid using `par(mfrow=c(4,4))`. However, I now have to add one more plot that needs to stand out a little in the grid and I wonder if there are ways to achieve a layout like this:
[image]

Are there packages out there, or other ways that may be of help? I do not use `ggplot`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `layout`. The matrix used in layout shows the location of each plot in the grid.  If a plot is referred to in multiple cells, it will extend into these. See ?layout for more information.

Here's a simple example:

```
mat = matrix(c(1,1,2,3,
               1,1,4,5,
               6,7,8,9,
               10,11,12,13,
               14,15,16,17), nrow=5, ncol=4, byrow = TRUE)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    1    2    3
# [2,]    1    1    4    5
# [3,]    6    7    8    9
# [4,]   10   11   12   13
# [5,]   14   15   16   17

layout(mat)
par(mar=c(2,2,2,2))
for (i in 1:17) print(hist(mtcars$mpg, main = NA))
```

[image]